# How can I add a transition between re-renders of a specific state value in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have the following code in a React and Sass project:

```
<header className="App-header" style={{backgroundColor: accentColour, color: accentColour}}>
```

accentColour is defined earlier using useState() and thus when I setAccentColour(newcolour), React re-renders the background to the new colour. My question is, how do I add a colour transition between the different colours - such that one background colour smoothly transitions into the next background colour when accentColour changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is something similar to this:

```
<header className="App-header" style={{ backgroundColor: `${accentColor}`, transitionDuration: '500ms' }}>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!